# Can't diff array when using [] for defining in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

When I use following code it works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
my @b = (1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10);
my @c = (2,1,4,3,6,5);

print "a: ".Dumper(@a)."\n";
print "b: ".Dumper(@b)."\n";
print "c: ".Dumper(@c)."\n";
print "a-b: ".Dumper(array_minus(@a, @b))."\n";
#print "b-a: ".Dumper(array_minus(@b, @a))."\n";
#print "c-b: ".Dumper(array_minus(@c, @b))."\n";
#print "b-c: ".Dumper(array_minus(@b, @c))."\n";
#print "a-c: ".Dumper(array_minus(@a, @c))."\n";
print "c-a: ".Dumper(array_minus(@c, @a))."\n";
print "c in a: ".Dumper(intersect(@c, @a))."\n";
```

However, when I use this type of declaration for array code doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);

my @a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
my @b = [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10];
my @c = [2,1,4,3,6,5];

print "a: ".Dumper(@a)."\n";
print "b: ".Dumper(@b)."\n";
print "c: ".Dumper(@c)."\n";
print "a-b: ".Dumper(array_minus(@a, @b))."\n";
#print "b-a: ".Dumper(array_minus(@b, @a))."\n";
#print "c-b: ".Dumper(array_minus(@c, @b))."\n";
#print "b-c: ".Dumper(array_minus(@b, @c))."\n";
#print "a-c: ".Dumper(array_minus(@a, @c))."\n";
print "c-a: ".Dumper(array_minus(@c, @a))."\n";
print "c in a: ".Dumper(intersect(@c, @a))."\n";
```

I need to define array using [] because in my original code when I use `Array::Diff->diff` it returns two array added and deleted which are stored using [] instead of () due to which my `array_minus`, intersect operations are failing.

Comment: Following is the output which I got
"a-b: $VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6
        ];

c-a: $VAR1 = [
          2,
          1,
          4,
          3,
          6,
          5
        ];

c in a:"
which is wrong

Comment: yes, Line 7 should be "my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6);". My mistake, sorry for that, I should have checked it.

Answer (score 5):

That's because these things do something completely different.

```
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6);

my @a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Square brackets define an anonymous list, returning a reference.  Therefore in the second case you effectively create a multi-dimensional data structure.

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6
        ];
```

Vs.

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
          ]
        ];
```

Note the extra bracket. You could access this as `@{$a[0]}` and get the same result in your code.

But the key purpose of the square bracket is to assign to a reference:

```
my $a_ref = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
print Dumper $a_ref;
```

Which is essentially what you're doing - take your second example:

```
my @a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 

print "a has ", scalar @a, " elements\n";
print join ("\n", @a );
```

This prints:

```
a has 1 elements
ARRAY(0x346dd4)
```

Because `@a` is a single element array, containing a reference, which Dumper "follows" to get at the rest of the data structure.

Chances are the function calls you're making aren't doing this, which is why it isn't working.